# Where can I check the official hardware requirements for old Windows versions?

Tags: windows, requirements

I am researching the hardware requirements about old Windows versions, like the following:

- XP 32 bit home
- XP 64 bit home
- XP with SP3 home
- XP 32 bit professional
- XP 64 bit professional
- XP with SP3 professional
- etc...

But I cannot get any info in the Microsoft website.

When can I find the most "official" information about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find the requirements on Microsoft website, you can use this snapshot from [Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20031003203956/http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/home/evaluation/sysreqs.asp) taken on 03 October 2003. It leads to a page with the title: "Windows XP Home Edition System Requirements" published on 24 August 2001 (the date Windows XP was relased to manufacturer).

You can then use the same website to move in time to search for other versions, service packs, etc.

**Links from Archive.org:**

[Windows XP Product Information](https://web.archive.org/web/20031002080642/http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/evaluation/default.asp)

[Windows XP Service Pack 2 Overview](https://web.archive.org/web/20041022060118/http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/sp2/overview.mspx)

[Windows XP Service Pack 3 Overview](https://web.archive.org/web/20080906084306/http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=68C48DAD-BC34-40BE-8D85-6BB4F56F5110&displaylang=en#filelist)

[Microsoft Windows XP 64-Bit Edition](https://web.archive.org/web/20041022033149/http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/64bit/default.mspx)